# ASP.NET Core and React gives Failed to start 'npm' / The directory name is invalid

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have a Core 2.2 project with Create React App in Visual Studio 2017 and after a 3 month pause on the project I am now returning but I cannot run the application anymore. When running the project I get this error in the browser;

```
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (Failed to start 'npm'...
```

It gives me two possibilities to resolve it;

```
Ensure that 'npm' is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories...
```

and

```
See the InnerException for further details of the cause. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The directory name is invalid
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.Npm.NpmScriptRunner.LaunchNodeProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.Npm.NpmScriptRunner.LaunchNodeProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.Npm.NpmScriptRunner..ctor(String workingDirectory, String scriptName, String arguments, IDictionary`2 envVars)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.ReactDevelopmentServer.ReactDevelopmentServerMiddleware.StartCreateReactAppServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
```

Npm is installed and is located in one of the suggested directories so that shouldnt be the issue. The files havent changed so cannot se why a directory name should be invalid - the only change since last is a Visual Studio versioning upgrade. I have installed VS2019 but it gives me same error. Debugging in VS doesnt break, the error only shows in the browser.

What to do?

Comment: Run `npm` in command windows, is there any error? If you create a new Core project with React app, does this issue exist?

Comment: npm, yarn etc runs perfect outside - and a new project works. But the issues is now solved using link below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the following issue on GitHub: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6342#issue-395713046

> 1. JavaScriptServices reports any failure in the call to npm as a PATH problem for NPM, 
>      when it's reasonably probable (if not more likely) that the real problem is the SourcePath was set to a directory that doesn't exist.
> 2. Our Templates SourcePath of "ClientApp" does not work in all circumstances

Comment: Updating the default SourcePath as described in the link made the magic - tnx!

Comment: I have the following:
`[2] See the InnerException for further details of the cause.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (267): The directory name is invalid.`
But i dont get what is wrong with it?

Comment: @keysersoze Can you be more specific re: how you solved this? Can't work it out from the link. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Setting source path as follows worked for me;

```
app.UseSpa(spa => 
{
       spa.Options.SourcePath = env.ContentRootPath+ "\\..\\" + "ShifuCodeClient";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
});
```